# Problem with \widehat{=} and $

Tags: errors, symbols, accents

when I´m using `\widehat{=}` or `\hat{=}` i get an error. Also the pdf output isn´t formatted as it should be.

```
\textbf{foo:} for example \textit{city} \widehat{=} \textit{attribute} and\texit{new york} \widehat{=} \textit{object}.
```

[image]

It should look like this:

- **foo:** for example *city* ≙ *attribute* and *new york* ≙ *object*.

What am I missing?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\widehat` is a math construction so you need math mode,  `$\widehat{=} $`

Answer (score 4):

Use `\mathrel{\widehat{=}}` to get the correct spacing around the relation symbol.

As already noted in the comments, the whole contructions only works in math mode, i.e., either inside a pair of $ signs, or in a mathematical environment like `equation`.

Answer (score 4):

Since your symbol seems to be used in text mode, I suggest defining a macro, that makes easier inputting the text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\is}[2]{\textit{#1}$\;\widehat{=}\;$\textit{#2}}

\begin{document}

For example \is{city}{attribute} and
\is{New York}{object}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this (`\equalhat`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,amsmath}
\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\stackon[1.5pt]{=}{%
  \stretchto{\scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{\wedge}{\rule{1ex}{3ex}}}{0.5ex}}}}

\begin{document}

$\equalhat$

\end{document}
```